# Eloquent Error when specifying table in where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this query:

```
$query = Product::query();

$query->join('models AS m', 'products.model_id', '=', 'm.id');

if ($request->has('q')) {
    $terms = explode(' ', $request->get('q'));
    $query->orWhereHas('products.name', function($q) use ($terms) { $q->whereIn('name', $terms); });
}
```

It's returning

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::products()
```

If I change products.category to anything else the error change to the new value for example:

```
$query->orWhereHas('s.name', function($q) use ($terms) { $q->whereIn('name', $terms); });
```

Will output

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::s()
```

I need to specify that category belongs to names because if I don't it returns ambiguous fields existence.

The reason I'm joining the models table is because I need to select a single field from model

```
$query->get(['products.id', 'products.name', 'products.front_image', 'products.back_image', 'products.slug', 'm.slug as model_slug'])
```

How can I specify table in where clause without getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

The `whereHas` method is for querying relations; the first argument should correspond with the name of a relationship method in your Model. In your case, the QueryBuilder is trying to call the method `products()` on the Product model.

If you're looking to query records by name, you can just use the `where()` method.